# HTML5 video not showing track close caption in iOS and Android devices

Tags: android, ios, html5-video, video.js

HTML5 video is not showing track close caption in iOS and Android devices? Please help me to get rid of this. I am using video.js 4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Tracks are not supported in all browsers yet. check #6 here for current state of the art: http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/